# SQL Loop sadness

Tags: sql, loops

Using Microsoft SQL 2008
I have a loop that should grab data from each row but it only seems to be grabbing the last row. 
The table is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST](
    [PK] [int] NULL,
    [ITEMS] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

insert into dbo.test (pk, items) values (1, '1111')
insert into dbo.test (pk, items) values (2, '2222')
insert into dbo.test (pk, items) values (3, '3333')
insert into dbo.test (pk, items) values (4, '4444')
```

I am trying to loop through it and grab the items per row for an insert but I am only getting the last row:

```
-- Get the number of rows in the looping table
DECLARE @RowCount INT
SET @RowCount = (SELECT COUNT(ITEMS) FROM dbo.TEST) 

Print @ROWCOUNT

-- Declare an iterator
DECLARE @I INT
-- Initialize the iterator
SET @I = 1

--Loop through the rows of a table 
WHILE (@I <= @RowCount)

BEGIN

Declare @Name varchar(100)

SELECT @Name = Lower(ITEMS) FROM dbo.TEST


PRINT 'Row No = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @I)

Print @Name

-- Increment the iterator
        SET @I = @I  + 1

END
```

The results I am getting are:

```
4
Row No = 1
4444
Row No = 2
4444
Row No = 3
4444
Row No = 4
```

Seems simple enough but I can't find any information on why this is happening and/or get my head around the loop and why it is not working.
Thank you,
Heather

Comment: I'm not a MSSQL expert, but your code is the exact same each time the loop is run (you aren't doing anything to @I other than incrementing it). If you're trying to get each row, one at a time, you'll need something like ` WHERE pk = @I`.

Comment: What's your intention with the [`LOWER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174400.aspx) -- it's meant to convert your column contents to lower case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Philip Kelley  noted  `SELECT @Name = Lower(ITEMS) FROM dbo.TEST` will always give you the last item in the result. So his solution (adding `WHERE PK = @I`) will work  if the PKs in the table start with 1 and are sequential. If either those conditions don't hold true then you'll have to do somthing like this.

```
;WITH CTE as 
(SELECT row_number() over (order by pk) rn, items
FROM dbo.TEST)
SELECT @Name = Lower(items) FROM CTE where rn = @i
```

Although in all honestly you're probably better of with `FAST_FORWARD` cursor since you've lost the set-based operations battle already.

See this [data.se query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2278/sample-for-8513177) for a working example (note I added another item `6,'6666'`)

Comment: True. I assumed (ooh, there's that word again!) that, since the loop was iterating over 1 to X, that the PK was a matching integer.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is in

```
SELECT @Name = Lower(ITEMS) FROM dbo.TEST
```

As written, it will read all rows in the table... but only one value can be assigned to @Name.  You need a where clause on it, like so:

```
SELECT @Name = Lower(ITEMS) FROM dbo.TEST 
WHERE PK = @I
```

Comment: Mind you now, I feel massive guilt for writing that answer. Nine times out of eight, you don't want to write procedural loops like that within SQL, as there is probably a set-based way to "solve the problem".  Unfortunately, without knowing what you're really doing within the loop, I can't offer advise on how to replace it with queries.

Comment: That, and the whole basis where we're using a counter and assuming it equals a row identifier ;)

Comment: I guess I should have made my table different. I am reading from a view that really doesn't have a pk so I am trying to loop through the table with and grab the items value on each row. With out a PK I do not know if it is feasible.  (the lower is just to match data in a file system that is all lower case)